# Padding and Masking a batch dataset

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

When representing multiple strings of natural language, the number of characters in each string may not be equal. Then, the return result could be placed in a [`tf.RaggedTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor?version=nightly#to_tensor), where the length of the innermost dimension varies depending on the number of characters in each string:

```py
rtensor = tf.ragged.constant([
                      [1, 2], 
                      [3, 4, 5],
                      [6]
                      ])
rtensor
#<tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]>
```

In turn, applying [`to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor?version=nightly#to_tensor) method, converts that `RaggedTensor` into a regular `tf.Tensor` and consequently apply the padding operation:

```py
batch_size=3
max_length=8
tensor = rtensor.to_tensor(default_value=0, shape=(batch_size, max_length))
#<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 8), dtype=int32, numpy=
#array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)>
```

Now, is there an approach to generate also an adjunct tensor showing what is original data and what is padding? For the example above it would be:

```py
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 8), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: `tf.math.not_equal(tensor, 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [thusv89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1699075) suggests, you can simply check for non-zero values. It can be as simple as converting to boolean and back.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

rtensor = tf.ragged.constant([[1, 2],
                              [3, 4, 5],
                              [6]])
batch_size = 3
max_length = 8
tensor = rtensor.to_tensor(default_value=0, shape=(batch_size, max_length))
mask = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.dtypes.cast(tensor, tf.bool), tensor.dtype)
print(mask.numpy())
# [[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

The only possible drawback is that you might have had `0` values originally. You could use some other value as default value when converting to a tensor, for example `-1`, if you know that your data is always going to be non-negative:

```py
tensor = rtensor.to_tensor(default_value=-1, shape=(batch_size, max_length))
mask = tf.dtypes.cast(tensor >= 0, tensor.dtype)
```

But if you want your mask to work for whatever values you have, you can also just use [`tf.ones_like`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ones_like) with the ragged tensor:

```py
rtensor_ones = tf.ones_like(rtensor)
mask = rtensor_ones.to_tensor(default_value=0, shape=(batch_size, max_length))
```

This way `mask` will always be one exactly where `rtensor` has a value.

Comment: Thank you @jdehesa and @ thushv89. This solution is extremely interesting since I have a large dataset to tokenize.